# NotSerializableException even while using transient

Tags: java, serialization, transient

I'm getting error:

> WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute DocumentFieldHelper for
>   session {idsession} java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   com.example.DocumentKind  
> while trying to Serialize class
>   DocumentFieldHelper.

Code for DocumentFieldHelper

```
private class DocumentFieldHelper implements Serializable
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private Map<String, Object> fieldValues;
            private String documentKind;
            public DocumentFieldHelper()
            {
                fieldValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            }
            public NativeDockindQuery createQuery()
            {
                try
                {
                    NativeDockindQuery ndq = NativeDockindQuery.create(this.getDocumentKind());
                    return ndq;
                } catch (EdmException e)
                {
                    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                return null;
            }
            public String getDocumentKind() {
                return documentKind;
            }
```

Code for NativeDockindQuery

```
public class NativeDockindQuery implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2001430456575525419L;
        private transient DocumentKind kind;
        public static NativeDockindQuery create(String kind) throws EdmException {
            return new NativeDockindQuery(DocumentKind.findByCn(kind), false);
        }
        private NativeDockindQuery(DocumentKind kind, boolean checkPermissions) throws EdmException {
            this.kind = kind;
        }
    }
```

Of course, there is more code but i think that is the important part.

I'm guessing that NativeDockindQuery has to be Serializable because it is return type in one of DocumentFieldHelper methods?

And is it possible that i have this problem because i'm using static method from DocumentKind?

Comment: What goes inside `fieldValues`?

Comment: I see two **documentKind** . One which is string variable in your **DocumentFieldHelper** and other looks like a class type in **NativeDockindQuery**. So is this alright  ? I mean have you mistaken something here ?

Comment: Vlad - fieldValues Object variables are primitives like int, long also String. Nothing what could not be serialized (espescially like DocumentKind which is pointed in error description)

Comment: SacJn - no, everything is fine. In DocumentFieldHelper documentKind is String. It is converted to DocumentKind class instance in create in NativeDockindQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i have done some tests and, of course, there was problem in other place than code posted by me. I should mention that this code isn't mine, i'm just making corrections when some bugs have been seen.
Turns out, DocumentFieldHelper class was inner class in some other class. The outer class has declared instance variable of DocumentKind class, thats why the problem showed up. I just made DocumentFieldHelper independent class from the outer class and everything is working just fine.
Lesson? Be carefull while serializing inner class.

Thanks Vlad and SacJn for responses.